# Multiple answer question on Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

IF $X$ and $Y$ are $n\times n$ matrices with real entries,then which of the following is/are TRUE?

$a)$If $P^{-1}XP$ is a diagonal for some real invertible matrix $P$,then there exist a basis for $\Bbb R^n$      consisting of eigenvectors of $X$.

$b)$If $X$ is diagonal with distinct diagonal entries and $XY=YX,$then $Y$ is also diagonal.

$c)$If $X^2$ is diagonal,then$X$ is diagonal.

$d)$If $X$ is diagonal  and $XY=YX$ for all $Y$,then $X=\beta I$ for some $\beta \in \Bbb R.$

I think $a $ and $b$ are correct options because of the definition of diagonalizable matrix but I am not sure about option $c $.Converse of option $c$ is correct.$c$ And one more doubt how to prove option $d$ is correct?Please help me to clear my doubts.Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: For c) consider $X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: $X$ is nilpotent matrix hence $X$ is not diagonalizable.Is it correct?

Comment: distinguish diagonal and diagonalizable!

Answer (score 1):

b) is true, but it does not seems to be the definition of diagonalizability.  Using the definition of the product, it turns out that the coefficient $(i,j)$ of $XY$ is $X_{i,i}Y_{i,j}$ while that of $YX$ is $X_{j,j}Y_{i,j}$. Therefore, for any $(i,j)$, 
$$\left( X_{i,i}-X_{j,j}\right)Y_{i,j}=0        $$
and for $i\neq j$, this quantity is zero, since   $X_{i,i}\neq  X_{j,j}$.

For c), as suggested in the comments, we can take a matrix $X$ such that $X^2\neq 0$ and which is not diagonal, for example $X=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$.

For d), let $E_{i,j}$ be the $n \times n$ matrix whose entry $(i,j)$ is $1$, and all the others zero. Compute $X E_{i,j}$ and $E_{i,j}X$.